# Access elements of pandas series

Tags: pandas, element, series

I have a dataframe and I want to extract the frequency of 0/1 in a particular column.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,1,0,1]})

df
Out[6]: 
   A
0  0
1  0
2  1
3  0
4  1
```

Calculating frequency of occurance of 0/1s -

```
df['A'].value_counts()
Out[8]: 
0    3
1    2
Name: A, dtype: int64

type(df['A'].value_counts())
Out[9]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

How can I extract the frequency of 0s and 1s, in lets suppose two variables, ones and zeros as -
 `zeros=3, ones=2`

Comment: `df['A'].value_counts().to_dict()`?

Comment: Hallo MayU. Nice to see you again. The code works perfectly, thanks. I would use it. But, is there a way to access directly from Series?

Comment: sure! `df['A'].value_counts().loc[0]`, `df['A'].value_counts().loc[1]`

Comment: Please add it to answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: added it to the answer...

Comment: Thanks MaxU, as always!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be bit more flexible to return a dictionary:

```
In [234]: df['A'].value_counts().to_dict()
Out[234]: {0: 3, 1: 2}
```

or

```
In [236]: d = df['A'].astype(str).replace(['0','1'], ['zeros','ones']).value_counts().to_dict()

In [237]: d
Out[237]: {'ones': 2, 'zeros': 3}

In [238]: d['ones']
Out[238]: 2

In [239]: d['zeros']
Out[239]: 3
```

you can also access it directly:

```
In [3]: df['A'].value_counts().loc[0]
Out[3]: 3

In [4]: df['A'].value_counts().loc[1]
Out[4]: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this issue is to use `collections library` and the function `counter()` in it.

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(df['A'])
c
Out[31]: Counter({0: 3, 1: 2})

count_0s=c.Counter(df['A'])[0]#Returns 3
count_1s=c.Counter(df['A'])[1]#Returns 2
```